# Using Light YouTube Embed with modal (reveal from Foundation) - how to stop video playback after modal window close?

Tags: youtube, zurb-foundation

I am using the latest [Foundation 6.4.x](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html) with the [Light YouTube Embeds script by @labnol](http://labnol.org/?p=27941).

I use this code in a standard html page:

```
<button data-toggle="animatedModalVideoTest1" class="hollow button expanded alert" href="##">View video</button>
```

And the corresponding Foundation reveal modal is this part:

```
<div class="reveal" id="animatedModalVideoTest1" data-reveal data-close-on-click="true" data-animation-in="fade-in" data-animation-out="fade-out">
<button class="button  float-right" data-close type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> Close modal window
</button>

 <div class="responsive-embed">
   <div class="youtube-player" data-id="xecEV4dSAXE"></div>
 </div>
```

When I click on "close window", the video keeps playing in the background. 
Any js pro who can suggest an idea how to stop this would be much appreciated :-)

PS: The video linked here is safe for work (John Oliver)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ..this link from zurb-forum: 
https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/39375-stop-video-when-closing-a-reveal-modal-with-foundation-6 .. works for me!

Insert `data-reset-on-close="true"` into your Markup.

Example

```
 <div class="large reveal" id="myvideo" data-reveal data-reset-on-close="true">

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyzzz?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

      <button class="close-button close-reveal-modal" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and many thanks for that - while the audio briefly stops playing, it continues after a second again when the modal is done closing. It might work for the way the video is directly loaded in your example, itis probably the Light YouTube Embed script that is messing with it. That however, I wanted to use to avoid 10 instances of the Youtube script being loaded when having ten modalson the page.